# APC results blank page after MySQL root password change

Tags: php, apc

I have APC installed via cPanel everything worked just fine until I set new MySQL root password.

After MySQL root password changed my web sites hosted on this box resulting blank page.

When I disable APC everything works fine, so I guess problem is APC related.

reinstall APC via cPanel does not help.

Q1: does APC need MySQL root password to work?

Q2: if so, how do I tell APC to use new root MySQL password?

Comment: Check the apache error logs for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APC and MySQL are not related to each other, and neither should affect the other.

You might want to look into your error logs for more information. Alternatively you can turn display_errors on and error_reporting to E_ALL | E_STRICT